# Fedora - fonts not recognized by apps despite packages being installed

Tags: fedora, fonts

I've had several font packages installed on my Fedora 20 machine, but for some reason - neither KDE nor Gnome apps notice them. Specifically, these are the Culmus Hebrew fonts (packages culmus-aharoni, culmus-drugulin etc.)

Is there something I should be doing? Is it a bug? A mis-feature?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong; I just installed the `culmus-aharoni-clm-fonts` package on my F22 system and it appears just fine (as Aharoni CLM):

```
fc-match Aharoni
AharoniCLM-Book.pfa: "Aharoni CLM" "Book"
```

But something weird may be going on on your system. Updating to F22 may fix this, or, you could also try rebuilding the font cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -f /usr/share/fonts/culmus
```

(Or, remove and reinstall the RPMs, which will do the same as part of the package install scripts.)

Comment: I'll ask my sysadmin to do this tomorrow (I don't have root on the machine actually, otherwise I would not have used Fedora in the first place).

Comment: But now that you've used it, you're converted, right? :)

Comment: Converted to Debian-based distros maybe :-( Seriously though, ever since the systemd thing took hold I'm thinking I should probably find me another distribution to "call home".

Comment: Back to topic, does the font show up with `fc-match`?